# Python, Error: "function is not defined" ,

Tags: python, class-method

I have 2 `@classmethod`: one of them is 'operators' and other one is 'pretty_print_2'.
in 'operators' i need to call 'pretty_print_2'.

The first method is as follow:

```
    @classmethod
def operators(cls, operator_filter=None, limit_filter=0, ncores=1, exec_mode='sync'):


    ...

    response = None
    try:
        if Cube.client is None:
            raise RuntimeError('Cube.client is None')

        query = 'oph_operators_list '

        if operator_filter is not None:
            query += 'operator_filter=' + str(operator_filter) + ';'
        if limit_filter is not None:
            query += 'limit_filter=' + str(limit_filter) + ';'
        if ncores is not None:
            query += 'ncores=' + str(ncores) + ';'
        if exec_mode is not None:
            query += 'exec_mode=' + str(exec_mode) + ';'

        if Cube.client.submit(query) is None:
            raise RuntimeError()

        if  Cube.client.last_response is not None:
            response = Cube.client.deserialize_response()


    except Exception as e:
        print(get_linenumber(), "Something went wrong:", e)
        raise RuntimeError()
    else:

        cls.pretty_print_2(response)
```

The second method is as follow:

```
@classmethod
def pretty_print_2(response):
```

but when i run the script I faced the following error:

```
 cls.pretty_print_2(response)
TypeError: pretty_print_2() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

I will be appreciated for any suggestion.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First argument in class methods should be cls i.e. the class itself. So your method:

```
@classmethod
def pretty_print_2(response)
```

should look like:

```
@classmethod
def pretty_print_2(cls, response)
```